# D3 Choropleth Map Color Scale doesn't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, choropleth

Good afternoon, 
I´m building this map in d3

[image]

However when i try making the connection to my dataset so it returns a map with the color scale, meaning each country whith a different color nothing happens.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
window.onload = set_choroplet();
d3.json("convertcsv.json").then(function (data) {
    full_dataset = data;
    console.log(full_dataset);
    console.log(full_dataset[1].Code);
});

function set_choroplet() {
    var w = 650;
    var h = 350;
    var svg = d3.select("#choropletMap")
      .append("svg") 
      .attr("width",w)
      .attr("height",h);

    var projection = d3.geoMercator().translate([w/2, h/2]).scale(100).center([15,60]);
    var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
    var data= d3.map();
    var colorScheme = d3.schemePurples[9];
    colorScheme.unshift("#eee");
    var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold().domain([0.01,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8])
      .range(colorScheme);
    var promise1 = d3.json("worldcountries.json");
    var promise2 =  d3.json("convertcsv.json", function(d) { 
        data.set(d.Code, +d.total);});
        Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(values) {
            // Draw map
            svg.selectAll("path")
              .data(values[0].features)
              .attr("class","continents")
              .enter().append("path")
              .attr("fill", function (d){
              // Pull data for this country and Set the color
              return colorScale(d.total = data.get(d.id));
        })
        .attr("d", path);
    });

}
```

*worldcountries.json* is the file that makes the selection of only asia, europe and north america countries.

*convertcsv.json* my dataset file. It is presented as follows:

```
    [
 {
   "Country": "Afghanistan           ",
   "total": 0.4,
   "2000_r": 100,
   "2001": 0.4,
   "2001_r": 100,
   "2002": 0.4,
   "2002_r": 100,
   "2003": 0.4,
   "2003_r": 100,
   "2004": 0.4,
   "2004_r": 100,
   "2005": 0.4,
   "2005_r": 100,
   "2006": 0.4,
   "2006_r": 100,
   "2007": 0.4,
   "2007_r": 100,
   "2008": 0.4,
   "2008_r": 100,
   "2009": 0.5,
   "2009_r": 100,
   "2010": 0.5,
   "2010_r": 100,
   "2011": 0.5,
   "2011_r": 100,
   "2012": 0.5,
   "2012_r": 99,
   "2013": 0.5,
   "2013_r": 99,
   "2014": 0.5,
   "2014_r": 99,
   "2015": 0.5,
   "2015_r": 98,
   "2016": 0.5,
   "2016_r": 99,
   "2017": 0.5,
   "2017_r": 99,
   "Code": "  AFG "
 },
 {
   "Country": "Albania               ",
   "total": 0.7,
   "2000_r": 67,
   "2001": 0.7,
   "2001_r": 67,
   "2002": 0.7,
   "2002_r": 67,
   "2003": 0.7,
   "2003_r": 66,
   "2004": 0.7,
   "2004_r": 65,
   "2005": 0.7,
   "2005_r": 63,
   "2006": 0.7,
   "2006_r": 64,
   "2007": 0.7,
   "2007_r": 64,
   "2008": 0.7,
   "2008_r": 65,
   "2009": 0.7,
   "2009_r": 64,
   "2010": 0.7,
   "2010_r": 61,
   "2011": 0.8,
   "2011_r": 60,
   "2012": 0.8,
   "2012_r": 58,
   "2013": 0.8,
   "2013_r": 57,
   "2014": 0.8,
   "2014_r": 58,
   "2015": 0.8,
   "2015_r": 58,
   "2016": 0.8,
   "2016_r": 58,
   "2017": 0.8,
   "2017_r": 57,
   "Code": "  ALB "
 },
 {
   "Country": "Armenia               ",
   "total": 0.6,
   "2000_r": 72,
   "2001": 0.7,
   "2001_r": 72,
   "2002": 0.7,
   "2002_r": 72,
   "2003": 0.7,
   "2003_r": 71,
   "2004": 0.7,
   "2004_r": 71,
   "2005": 0.7,
   "2005_r": 70,
   "2006": 0.7,
   "2006_r": 67,
   "2007": 0.7,
   "2007_r": 65,
   "2008": 0.7,
   "2008_r": 64,
   "2009": 0.7,
   "2009_r": 66,
   "2010": 0.7,
   "2010_r": 68,
   "2011": 0.7,
   "2011_r": 67,
   "2012": 0.7,
   "2012_r": 67,
   "2013": 0.7,
   "2013_r": 67,
   "2014": 0.7,
   "2014_r": 67,
   "2015": 0.7,
   "2015_r": 66,
   "2016": 0.7,
   "2016_r": 66,
   "2017": 0.8,
   "2017_r": 66,
   "Code": "  ARM "
 },
 {
   "Country": "Austria               ",
   "total": 0.8,
   "2000_r": 18,
   "2001": 0.8,
   "2001_r": 18,
   "2002": 0.8,
   "2002_r": 20,
   "2003": 0.8,
   "2003_r": 20,
   "2004": 0.8,
   "2004_r": 20,
   "2005": 0.9,
   "2005_r": 21,
   "2006": 0.9,
   "2006_r": 22,
   "2007": 0.9,
   "2007_r": 16,
   "2008": 0.9,
   "2008_r": 15,
   "2009": 0.9,
   "2009_r": 14,
   "2010": 0.9,
   "2010_r": 14,
   "2011": 0.9,
   "2011_r": 14,
   "2012": 0.9,
   "2012_r": 14,
   "2013": 0.9,
   "2013_r": 16,
   "2014": 0.9,
   "2014_r": 16,
   "2015": 0.9,
   "2015_r": 16,
   "2016": 0.9,
   "2016_r": 16,
   "2017": 0.9,
   "2017_r": 16,
   "Code": "  AUT "
 }]
```

Can you please help me to understand how can I make the color scale working??

Thank you!!

Comment: could it be related to the extra "tab"/"spaces" in the `Country:` values?